# How to disable Windows 8 (WinRT) Lock Screen

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

This is how you do it on Windows Phone
http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2011/11/mango-sample-lock-and-run.html

That is NOT how you do it Windows 8.

Is there a way to do it in Windows 8 apps, too?

Comment: It looks like everything you need to know about this is already on the page you linked.

Comment: WinRT! Not Windows Phone! Sheesh

Comment: I've reopened your question, but you need to help us out a little.  Did the Windows Phone code not work?  Why?  It should have; as Microsoft points out, ["it's just Windows,"](http://www.zdnet.com/cleaning-up-microsofts-metro-mess-7000002113/) and it's hard to believe that Microsoft deliberately broke compatibility, unless you are no longer allowed to disable the lock screen from code.  Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Windows Phone API is 100% different. The answer below is correct. Thank you for reopening the question, I adjusted the title to be more clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the [Windows.System.Display.DisplayRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241816.aspx) class. The [requestActive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.display.displayrequest.requestactive.aspx#Y0) method allows you to keep the display active when it would otherwise be dimmed and turned off. Be sure to call [requestRelease](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.display.displayrequest.requestrelease.aspx) once for each time that you call requestActive so that the display can get back to its power-conscious behavior when you no longer need it to stay on.